# JQuery Internals Documentation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Is there any documentation available that explains the internals of JQuery and JQuery UI?

I have been looking through the source code, and while much of it makes sense, I was still hoping for an overview/walkthrough of the source code to help speed up my learning process.

I'm not looking for general documentation of how to use JQuery, as I already have a fairly good understanding of the library.

Thanks

Comment: Long shot here, you could try reading the commit notes on the github project.

Comment: check this also : http://jqueryui.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For jQueryUI a good place is the [planning and design wiki](http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/) in particular the [Widget Factory](http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/Widget-factory) that all jQueryUI plugins use and is the recomended pattern for creating custom widgets.

There is a [UI developers guide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide) which also touches on some stuff in core, like jQuery.fn and jQuery.data.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

If you want to lean jquery. you also watch the lynda.com "learn jquery videos" that help you for your learning process or you can also download the jquery videos from torrents.

Comment: He wants to learn the internals of jQuery, not the outside API